# How to create a full text index with pymodm

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymodm

I'm not completely sure how to create a full text index with PyModm.

My `Meta` class looks like this:

```py
lass Meta:
        write_concern = WriteConcern(j=True)
        indexes = [
            pymongo.IndexModel([("name", "text"), ("description", "text")])
        ]
```

However, when I attempt to run the raw query using `get_queryset().raw()`

```py
{
    "$text": {"$search": query}
}
```

No results are returned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

Apparently, I just needed to provide a list of `(field, 'text')` tuples

i.e.

```py
index = [
    pymongo.IndexModel([
        ("first_field", "text"),
        ("second_field", "text")
    ])
]
```